# Excel - Compare tables from different sheets with dynamic column criterias

Tags: excel, vba

I need to be able to compare tables from two different worksheets/workbooks. These tables will have different number of columns but the user should be able to pick and choose which columns are unique and which columns are quantity columns.

For examples:
Table1, the user chooses columns A, B, and D to be unique, and column F to be the quantity column.
Table2, the user chooses columns B, C, and E to be unique, and column G to be the quantity column.

The code will then **find** a row with columns A, B and D from Table1 that matches a row with columns B, C, and E from Table2, **get the difference** in column F from Table1 and column G from Table2 and **paste** it in a new column at the end of Table2.

Not sure how to utilize the ArrayList as I don't know how to compare all the ArrayList items simultaneously. Would appreciate if you could suggest a method of approaching this problem.

Note : the amount of unique columns chosen should be dynamic (there can be between 1 to 10 unique columns) and will be the same for both Table1 and Table2. Below is my very rough code.

```
Sub compare_tables()

Dim wbMain As Workbook
Dim wsMain As Worksheet

Set wbMain = ActiveWorkbook
Set wsMain = wbMain.ActiveSheet

' Select the Excel file to compare with

' Open the Excel file

Dim wbSub As Workbook
Dim wsSub As Worksheet

Set wbSub = ActiveWorkbook

' Select the sheet number
Dim subsheet As Long

subsheet = InputBox("Please input the sheet number for the reference table.")

Set wsSub = wbSub.Sheets(subsheet)

' User inputs the unique columns (number or letter) in Table A and have it stored in UniqueList1
' User inputs the quantity column (number or letter) in Table A and have it stored in QuantityList1

' User inputs the unique columns (number or letter) in Table A and have it stored in UniqueList2
' User inputs the quatity column (number or letter) in Table A and have it stored in QuantityList2

' Pseudo loop : Dim rowCount as Long
' mainRowCount = wbMain.UsedRange.Rows.Count
' subColCount = wsSub.UsedRange.Col.Count
' Dim i As Int
' Dim l As Int
' Dim diff As Int
' For i = 1 To rowCount
'   For l = 1 To rowCount
'       If wsMain.Cells(i, UniqueList1(all)) = wsSub.Cells(l, UniqueList2(all))
'       diff = wsMain.Cells(i, QuantityList1) - wsSub(l, QuantityList2)
'       wsSub.Cells(l, subColCount + 1) = diff
'   Next
' Next

End Sub
```

Comment: This looks more like a list of requirements than a problem you are having with your code. This is out of scope for Stack Overflow. When you have something close to working, but need help with a specific part of your code, that is when you can ask about it here.

Comment: @braX Alright thank you :)